# preg_replace between anything between {} problems with javascripts

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need help to solve this problem. I am not good in preg patterns, so maybe it is very simple :)

I have this one preg_replace in my template system:

```
$code = preg_replace('#\{([a-z0-9\-_].*?)\}#is', '\1', $code);
```

which works fine, but in case i have some javascript code like this google plus button:

`window.___gcfg = {lang: 'sk'};`

it replaces is to this one:

```
window.___gcfg = ;
```

I tried this pattern: `#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#is`

That works well with gplus button, but when I have some like this (google adsense code) `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

result is `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push();`

I need rule to be applied something like this, but I dont know why it is not working

`\{([a-z0-9-_])\}` - Just letters, numbers, underscore and dash. Anything else i need to keep as it is.

Thank you for answers.

Edit:
More simple example of what I need:

```
{SOMETHING} -> do rewrite
{A_SOMETHING} -> do rewrite
{} -> do not rewrite
{name : 'me'} -> do not rewrite
```

So if there is something other than a-z0-9-_ or if there is nothing between {}, just do not rewrite and skip that.

Comment: What is the original task? There is a built in json parser in php

Comment: Use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: Thankn you, but + is not working, task as I said is part of template system, json parser is not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like you want to match curly braces where the contents are solely a-z0-9_-.
In that case, try:

```
$code = preg_replace('#\{([a-z0-9\-_]+?)\}#is',
                     'whatever_you_wanted_to_replace_with',
                     $code);
```

Your original regex said "match [a-z0-9_-] followed by 0 or more of anything" (the `.*?`).
This one says "match 1 or more of `[a-z0-9_-]`".

As to what you want to *replace* such things with, you haven't made it clear, so I assume you can do that bit.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not solution I am looking for, I have edited frist post with simple example.

Comment: Rewrite with *what*? Also, have updated my answer to reflect your question (now that you have clarified what you want to match and what is wrong, your question is totally different to what it was originally, and much easier to understand!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search script substrings with the first part of the pattern and your template tags with the second part. A script substring will be replaced by itself, and a template tag with its content.

Since the pattern uses the branch reset feature `(?|...|...)` the capture groups have the same number *(i.e. the number 1)*.

```
$pattern = '#(?|(<script\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/script>))+</script>)|{([\w-]++)})#i';
$code = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $code);
```

Note that you can do the same without the branch reset feature, but you must change the replacement pattern:

```
$pattern = '#(<script\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/script>))+</script>)|{([\w-]++)}#i';
$code = preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $code);
```

An other way consists to use the backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` to skip script substrings. `(*SKIP)` forces to not retry the substring (matched before with subpattern on its left) when the subpattern on its right fails. `(*FAIL)` makes the pattern fail immediately:

```
$pattern = '#<script\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/script>))+</script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{([\w-]++)}#i';
$code = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $code);
```

The difference with the two precedent patterns is that you don't need at all to put any reference for script substrings in the replacement pattern.